# Magento 2 how to get order information using soap api

Tags: magento2, sales-order, soap-api-v2

I want to get order information using soap API

```
    $wsdlUrl = 'http://website.com/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1';
$serviceArgs = array('searchCriteria' =>
    array('filterGroups' =>
        array('filters' =>
            array('field' => 'increment_id',
                'value' => '000000002',
                'condition_type' => 'eq')
        )
    ));

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'stream_context' => $context]);

$soapResponse =  $soapClient->__call('salesOrderRepositoryV1GetList', $serviceArgs);
```

if anyone knows about that then please let me know how to get the information?

Comment: Have you try the code and face any issue?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes. soap API failed to load external entity "/soap/default?WSDL service=sales Order Repository

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Just add your url, and api username and password.

```
    <?php

    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 

     $session = $proxy->login('user', 'password'); 

     $result = $proxy->salesOrderInfo($session, '100000064');

     var_dump($result);
```